# Number of ways to arrange pairs of integers with distance constraint

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computational-complexity

Given a sequence 0,1,1,2,2,3,3,...,n,n, find the number of ways to arrange the elements in the sequence so that there's exactly one digit between the two 1's, two digits between the two 2's, three digits between the two 3's, so on and so forth, and there are exactly n digits between the two n's.

For n=2, a possible solution would be 12102. For n=5, a possible solution would be 53141352402.

I have calculated that when n=2, the answer is 2; when n=3, the answer is 6; when n=4, the answer is 10; and when n=5, the answer is 22. But when n=6, my raw permutation function looks over 13! values and takes over an hour to calculate on my computer. I cannot think of any combinatorial enumeration or dynamic programming methods for this either. The best I can manage at the moment is backtracking with symmetry.

So my question is, what is the fastest way to compute the answer to this question for a large n and what are the mathematical intuitions for this problem? For example, is there a nontrivial upper / lower bound for the computational complexity for this problem?

Thanks for the answers in advance.

I first came across this problem in a Chinese coder forum.

Comment: Interesting question and OEIS is no  help. It might be useful for you toe [edit] the question to tell us where the problem comes from and why it matters to you.

Comment: For $n=6$ there are only $\frac {13!}{2!^6}$ possible sequences because swapping elements of a pair gives the same sequence.

Comment: Obviously, you mean numbers not digits.

Comment: I'm starting to get the feeling that a lower bound can be established through something similar to the reduction of SAT to hamiltonian path.

Comment: Are you interested in the complexity of the best possible algorithm, or in the actual answer because you need to calculate it?

Comment: i do not need to calculate it, i'm more interested in gaining insight into the problem

Answer (score 2):

An observation (too long for comment) that may speed up your recursive backtracking (though probably not by an order of magnitude).

In an acceptable permutation, the first occurrence of $k$ in position $p$ forces $k$ in position $k+p+1$ and precludes continuing with $k(k-1)$ or $kx(k-2)$ or $kxx(k-3)$ and so on.

Since half the entries are forced by the first occurrences of each $k$ you should have to examine something like $(n/2)!$ permutations, not all $n!$.

Answer (score 2):

Using the insight from @EthanBolker's answer, I wrote a quick script in Python which seems to work for the first several, which I compute are:

[1, 2, 6, 10, 22, 76, 364, 1876, 8316, 46768]

For larger values, I would probably need to try a more efficient approach, like using a generator instead of a list of all of the permutations like this script does.

```
import itertools

maxn = 10
counts = [None]*(maxn-1)
for i in range(1,maxn):
    print(f"\nFor {i}:")
    total = 0
    nums = list(range(i+1))
    
    # all permutations of the integers from 0 to i
    perms = list(itertools.permutations(nums))
    
    # try each permutation:
    for j in range(len(perms)):
        
        # create a list to contain the digits
        slots = [None]*(2*i+1)
        
        # go through the digits in that order
        for k in perms[j]:
            
            # see if there is an open entry
            try:
                n = slots.index(None)
            except ValueError:
                n = -1
                
            # if not, the list matches the pattern
            if n == -1:
                total += 1
                #print(slots)
                break
                
            # fill the first open entry with the next digit
            slots[n] = k
            
            # if the corresponding entry doesn't exist... break
            if n+k+1>=(2*i+1):
                break
                
            if k!=0:
                
                # if the corresponding entry is open... fill it also
                if slots[n+k+1] == None:
                    slots[n+k+1] = k
                
                # or is already full... break
                else:
                    break
                    
        # if the list is full, then it matches the pattern
        try:
            n = slots.index(None)
        except ValueError:
            n = -1
        if n == -1:
            total += 1
            #print(slots)
            
    # record the total matches for this value of i
    counts[i-1] = total
    print(f"\tTotal = {total}\n")
    
print(counts)
```

The print statements could be uncommented to if you wanted to see the strings that it computes as matching the pattern.

Comment: Nice. I was about to write  pseudocode - now I don't have to. I think you should post this sequence and your code on OEIS.

Comment: I would want to clean this code up before posting it as anything permanent, which is why I made sure to call it a “quick script”. First, creating the list of permutations definitely isn’t the way to go. That severely limits the values that can be computed.  I also think I could make it only check for ```None``` once per loop, and putting the ```break``` before the assignment might be more efficient.

Comment: But the most interesting observation I had was that there are two reasons to break: the corresponding entry (1) is already full, a “collision”, or (2) doesn’t exist, “out of range”. If a collision occurs, then the sequence of numbers that created it will never be an initial sequence. If an “out of range” occurs, that sequence may be able to be the initial sequence for longer words (but I’m not sure). It may be possible to use memoization with (1) to achieve much more efficient computation.

Comment: Yes - I was surprised that you started with a list of all the permutations. My thought was to build the legal permutations recursively an entry at a time, filling  more than one slot when possible. That generates restrictions that abort the construction - one hopes often enough.

Comment: If you want to improve the code and post your improved code on OEIS, please be my guest. I have other code that needs my attention, so I don’t plan on spending more time on this.

Comment: Perhaps I will. I'm retired and have no other commitments. THe ratios of successive values suggest (vaguely)  growth by a factor of $4.5$ or $5.5$ depending on the parity of $n$. They are $2.00, 3.00, 1.67, 2.20, 3.45, 4.79, 5.15, 4.43, 5.62$ so much slower than factorial.

Comment: Yes, I wonder if the growth is bounded by a polynomial.  I suspect that memoization of invalid initial sequences would give the greatest reduction in computation cost for large $n$. Good luck! I hope you’ll post your results here!